# Coded Web Test: Close a stream after a given amount of time

Tags: c#, load-testing, web-testing

I am looking for a way to close a WebTest response stream (JSON Object) without having to use the timeout property as it makes the test fail and not always works, the reason to do this is that the stream ticks infinitely unless it is closed by the client, right now my tests just time out because I haven't found a way to close them from code.

The JSON object doesn't need to be valid, but an example of an object and how it looks like when streamed can be found here:  http://tradestation.github.io/webapi-docs/en/stream/

My load test parses an IISLog and then it sends the Web API requests it finds as WebTestRequests, some of those requests are answered with JSON objects that stream endlessly and I need to close those streams based on the time it took the request to complete in the  IISlog.

```
 public class WebTest1Coded : WebTest
{
    public WebTest1Coded()
    {
        this.PreAuthenticate = true;
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        //Substitute the highlighted path with the path of the iis log file 
        IISLogReader reader = new IISLogReader(@"C:\IisLogsToWebPerfTest\TestData\log.log");
        foreach (WebTestRequest request in reader.GetRequests())
        {
            if (this.LastResponse != null) {
                this.LastResponse.HtmlDocument.ToString();

            }
            yield return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does truncation mean? Just chop of the end leaving malformed JSON? Or, some clever omission of sections but leaving valid JSON? What impact does the timer have? Does the size of the output relate to the timer value? You need to show examples of the input JSON and the truncated output including how that is impacted by the timer. Also show what you have already tried.

Comment: I just want to close the stream after a few seconds or minutes or whatever the IISLog request row specifies, it doesn't matter if the JSON object is valid or not. The output and the timer value do not relate. I will reformulate my question to be easier to understand.
Thanks!

Comment: I repeat, what have you tried? The question has nothing about how one can stop the JSON stream, does its documentation say what to do? When do you want to stop the stream and how do you detect that occurrence?

Comment: I have tried to timeout the test itself as the documentation shows no way to close the stream using WebTestRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.aspx).

Comment: Btw, I want to stop the stream exactly 2 minutes after it starts streaming.

Comment: Surely only the sending end can close the stream and stop sending it. How do you instruct the sender to stop sending? How does a real reader of the stream stop receiving it?